# Get complete rows from table for the smallest value of X for each value of Y; MySQL GROUP BY not working as expected

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

**UPDATE** SQLFiddle to try against is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c815

I have two tables, `trips` and `checkpoints` where there are multiple checkpoints for a given trip.  They join on the `trip_id` column.  The schemas (simplified) are these:

```
+-----------+     +--------------+
| trips     |     | checkpoints  |
+-----------+     +--------------+
| trip_id   |     | checkpint_id |
| driver_id |     | point_num    |
| other1    |     | trip_id      |
| other2    |     | scheduled    |
+-----------+     +--------------+
```

Here is my first query, which works as expected:

```
select driver_id,checkpoint_id,trip_id,min(scheduled) as scheduled
    from trips left join checkpoints on checkpoints.trip_id=trips.trip_id
    group by trip_id having scheduled like '2017-04-28%';
+-----------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| driver_id | checkpoint_id | trip_id | scheduled           |
+-----------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
|       110 |          1345 |     113 | 2017-04-28 18:29:00 |
|       107 |          4549 |     380 | 2017-04-28 17:57:00 |
|      NULL |          9277 |     774 | 2017-04-28 11:20:00 |
|        23 |          9301 |     776 | 2017-04-28 20:55:00 |
|        23 |          9937 |     829 | 2017-04-28 09:30:00 |
|       106 |          9949 |     830 | 2017-04-28 09:30:00 |
|        32 |         10141 |     846 | 2017-04-28 08:05:00 |
|      NULL |         10393 |     867 | 2017-04-28 15:45:00 |
|       132 |         10861 |     906 | 2017-04-28 11:26:00 |
|        32 |         11221 |     936 | 2017-04-28 10:16:00 |
|      NULL |         11245 |     938 | 2017-04-28 04:15:00 |
|       107 |         11461 |     956 | 2017-04-28 21:39:00 |
|        67 |         11473 |     957 | 2017-04-28 20:48:00 |
|        88 |         11569 |     965 | 2017-04-28 17:43:00 |
|       106 |         11581 |     966 | 2017-04-28 13:57:00 |
|       132 |         11593 |     967 | 2017-04-28 08:09:00 |
|       117 |         11605 |     968 | 2017-04-28 08:55:00 |
|        23 |         11617 |     969 | 2017-04-28 16:19:00 |
|        32 |         11629 |     970 | 2017-04-28 13:18:00 |
|        23 |         11641 |     971 | 2017-04-28 13:04:00 |
|        88 |         11653 |     972 | 2017-04-28 11:28:00 |
|        88 |         11665 |     973 | 2017-04-28 18:25:00 |
|        67 |         11677 |     974 | 2017-04-28 11:39:00 |
|       107 |         11845 |     988 | 2017-04-28 14:50:00 |
|       110 |         11857 |     989 | 2017-04-28 15:21:00 |
|        67 |         11869 |     990 | 2017-04-28 18:50:00 |
|        23 |         11881 |     991 | 2017-04-28 19:29:00 |
|      NULL |         11893 |     992 | 2017-04-28 19:15:00 |
+-----------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
28 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

When I execute this I see drivers #23 and #106 both have multiple trips, but their earliest records are these:

```
|        23 |          9937 |     829 | 2017-04-28 09:30:00 |
|       106 |          9949 |     830 | 2017-04-28 09:30:00 |
```

I've been trying to build the query which gets the lowest //complete row// (by the `scheduled` column) from the `checkpoints` table for each trip, joined on the `trips` table (to get the driver number) just for each driver.

I would have expected these rows to come from this query, but as you can see the results do not match; it seems to be randomly mixing-and-matching the checkpoint rows, assigning the lowest "scheduled" value to the first matching driver_id from the previous table's results:

```
select driver_id, checkpoint_id, temp.trip_id, MIN(scheduled) AS scheduled
    from
      (select driver_id,checkpoint_id,trip_id,min(scheduled) as scheduled 
            from trips left join checkpoints
                on trips.trip_id=checkpoints.trip_id
                where scheduled>='2017-04-28 00:00:00'
                   and scheduled<'2018-04-29 00:00:00'
                group by checkpoints.trip_id)
      temp
    GROUP BY driver_id;
+-----------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| driver_id | checkpoint_id | trip_id | scheduled           |
+-----------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
|      NULL |          1237 |     104 | 2017-04-28 04:15:00 |
|        23 |          9301 |     776 | 2017-04-28 09:30:00 |
|        32 |          6073 |     507 | 2017-04-28 08:05:00 |
|        51 |          9421 |     786 | 2017-05-01 12:20:00 |
|        67 |          7610 |     635 | 2017-04-28 00:34:00 |
|        70 |          9997 |     834 | 2017-04-29 09:22:00 |
|        88 |         11269 |     940 | 2017-04-28 11:28:00 |
|       106 |          1357 |     114 | 2017-04-28 09:30:00 |
|       107 |          4549 |     380 | 2017-04-28 14:50:00 |
|       110 |          1345 |     113 | 2017-04-28 00:03:00 |
|       116 |         11905 |     993 | 2017-04-29 00:13:00 |
|       117 |         11049 |     921 | 2017-04-28 00:30:00 |
|       132 |          9337 |     779 | 2017-04-28 08:09:00 |
+-----------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
13 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

What is the simplest and quickest (in terms of MySQL response time) way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample SQL Fiddle to try the queries against: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c815

Comment: What is the schema of the two tables __trips__ and __checkpoints__? BTW, a schema is not a select statement.

Comment: Added, my mistake.  I meant to do it and after pasting the query forgot I left that part blank.  Poor proofreading on my part.

Comment: Your expectations are incorrect. `GROUP BY` does not select rows from the tables. It creates rows using the values from each group. Even the first query you assume it works as expected, in fact, doesn't work. It apparently works now but it might return different results after you delete some rows from the table and insert them again; or if you export the table and import it on a different server.

Comment: @axiac Can you give me an example?  I thought the group by worked with the `MIN` function to grab the smallest date time per the grouping column (trip id instead the case of the first query).  If it doesn't, then what good is group by if it's randomly selecting a row?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT
    a.driver_id,
    c.checkpoint_id,
    c.trip_id,
    c.scheduled
FROM trips a
JOIN (
        SELECT 
            b.checkpoint_id,
            b.trip_id,
            min(b.scheduled) as scheduled
        FROM checkpoints b
        WHERE b.scheduled between '2017-04-28 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-29 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY b.checkpoint_id,b.trip_id
    ) c
ON c.trip_id = a.trip_id
GROUP BY driver_id
ORDER BY a.driver_id, c.scheduled
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c815/13/0)

Comment: `Unknown column 'a.trip_id' in 'where clause'` -- Does the inner query have awareness of the parent?

Comment: I added an SQL fiddle to the original question to test the queries.  After your edit the `LIMIT 1` causes only one row to show in the final result.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, forgot to remove it when I added the min function.

Comment: That's not grouping by the driver though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c815/4

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: The first row (that is: driver_id 23) in that output has a trip_id of 776 and a scheduled time of 20:55, much later than the 09:30 of trip_id 829.

It's matching the trip_id with the scheduled time correctly, but it's not getting the earliest records.

Comment: Yet Another Update - LOL. Changed the group by on the sub-query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142980/discussion-between-bing-and-sloan-thrasher).

Comment: (Only suggested chat because StackOverflow did.)  I'm still getting the same result for driver #23 with you latest update (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c815/13).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

```
select t.driver_id, c.checkpoint_id, c.trip_id, c.scheduled
from trips t
innerjoin checkpoints c on t.trip_id = c.trip_id 
inner join 
      (select trip_id, min(scheduled) as scheduled 
            from checkpoints
            group by trip_id) temp 
on c.trip_id = temp.trip_id and temp.scheduled = c.scheduled;
```

EDIT ACCORDING OUR COMMENTS:

```
select t.driver_id, min(c.checkpoint_id) as checkpoint_id, c.trip_id, c.scheduled
from trips t
inner join checkpoints c on t.trip_id = c.trip_id 
inner join 
  (select trip_id, min(scheduled) as scheduled 
        from checkpoints
        group by trip_id) temp 
on c.trip_id = temp.trip_id and temp.scheduled = c.scheduled
group by t.driver_id, c.trip_id, c.scheduled;
```

EDIT 2 (new):

```
select t.driver_id, min(c.checkpoint_id), min(c.trip_id), c.scheduled
from trips t
inner join 
(select trip_id, min(checkpoint_id) as checkpoint_id, min(scheduled) as scheduled 
    from checkpoints
    group by trip_id) c 
on t.trip_id = c.trip_id
group by t.driver_id;
```

Comment: That gave 1000s of records at first because it lacked the timestamp range (to only get 2017-04-28 dates).  I added the time range check to the (`from checkpoints` bit) but it still gave me multiple per driver.  So I added a `group by driver_id` to the *very* end and it gave me one row, but not always the row with min scheduled.  If I wrapped the `c.scheduled` in `MIN()` it gives the same mismatch problem as I gave in my original example.

Comment: I added an SQLFiddle to the question to test queries against: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c815

Comment: Yes, but I need to know the driver, trip_id, scheduled time and the checkpoint_id with it.

Comment: The edited query gives many rows per driver, since group by with multiple values gives one grouping per combination of each value (so group by driver_id, scheduled gives one record for each distinct driver_id-schedule(timestamp) PAIRING.  Try copy pasting your query into the SQL fiddle and you can see what I mean.

Comment: Just saw your edit #2 -- the times are right, but the trip_id doesn't match.  For driver #23 it's showing the 09:30 time (which is correct) but it's showing it for the trip_id 776 when 776's time is actually 20:55 (as shown in my original post).  Here's the Fiddle for your second update which shows 776 and 09:30 (you can see 776 is at 20:55 in the schema values on code line 44): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c815/35

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
trips,
(select a.* from 
checkpoints a
left outer join
checkpoints b
on a.trip_id = b.trip_id
and a.scheduled > b.scheduled
where b.scheduled is null) other
where trips.trip_id = other.trip_id;
```

This works with your duplicated scheduled times: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a395f/6

Comment: That code (posted 2017-04-30 19:11:26Z) produces this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c815/44  I'm only looking for one row per driver -- the one with the lowest checkpoint row (by scheduled column).

Comment: Is it the lowest scheduled time or not?  If so, the problem is you have multiple rows with the same scheduled value for the same trip id.  If you fix that, this is the standard solution that works.  If you want the row with the earliest point_num, you can replace scheduled with point_num above.

Comment: Why is that a problem?  None of the lowest timestamps seem to be returned (per my driver #23 and #106 examples), at least not in conjunction with the appropriate trip_id and checkpoint_id data.

Comment: Because that's how SQL works...  The lowest times show up here for me now... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a395f/2

Comment: I didn't notice in your previous fiddle, but you removed all the other rows from the schema, though.  If you run it against the complete data set it still gives more than one row per driver: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c815/57